# PressPi (Wordpress) Broken Layout

Tags: wp-config, server, outside-wordpress, ip

We have a Raspberry Pi running [PressPi](http://presspi.com/) which is a wordpress server. Our goal is to setup a Captive Portal using dnsmasq where users who connect to the Pi using a USB WiFi adapter see the PressPi home page when they attempt to surf the web. `/etc/networks/interfaces` (Rasbian) has been configured with a static IP address and correctly leases an IP address to clients. When these clients navigate to the PressPi server using the Pi's IP address, they see a broken layout whereas connecting to the Pi at `http://localhost/` using the Pi's desktop renders the PressPi home page correctly.

Tried and failed:

- I'm not familiar with Nginx and thinking it could be an issue with its configuration, I installed and configured Apache2 but this didn't fix the issue.
- Confirmed that the entire directory including its content is owned by
  `www-data` and tried different permissions (`775`, `755`, `777`), all
  to no avail.
- Setup a fairly complex HTML site and that rendered properly over the
  network.
- Viewed all associated log files and there was no information related
  to my current problem. And that was expected since there were no
  errors.
- Manually updated `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` to the Pi's static address (`http://192.168.1.185`) by defining them in the `wp-config.php` file and confirmed the change from the Admin CP.

I can't think of any reason why I get a broken display over the network, but not on the Pi's desktop. I appreciate any suggestions.

**UPDATE**
This *is* a Wordpress problem. I suspect something to do with a path update as other applications render properly over the network.

Comment: maybe it is a wordpress problem, maybe not (most likely it is not and it is a server, theme or plugin problem). One thing is sure, you didn't provide any detail that will enable anyone to help you.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Thanks for your comment. What additional information should I provide?

Comment: frankly, you need to isolate the problem otherwise there are just too many posibilities. Is the problem is with the theme and other themes work currectly? maybe it is a specific plugin? and does it happen because a css fails o load, or maybe some different css is loaded? and if fails to load do you get any error in your nginx log?. Most likely after you have issolated the actual issue the solution will be obvious even to you, but even if not at least it will be possible to try to have some educated guess were the problem might be and suggest additional debugging steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is late, and you might have found the answer already, but I suspect you'll need to do a serialized search and replace on the DB. You can't just change the WP domain name in wp-config.php. The database still has entries for the setup domain name, whatever that might be (localhost?). You can use this tool: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

I use version 2, as it is just a .php file, but version 3 has a more useful interface. You'll need the DB creds, the old url ("localhost"), and the new one (your IP, in this case.) After this, you'll only be able to see a working, non-broken version, at the IP.